# ZF2 Navigation: Activate route with parameters other than default?

Tags: php, navigation, routes, zend-framework2

This seems to be a similar problem but didn't work for me. I feel like the answer must be out there -- this can't be an uncommon issue -- but I'm not using the correct search terms.

[ZF2: Active branch for child routes in zend navigation. How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504590/zf2-active-branch-for-child-routes-in-zend-navigation-how)

Here is a route I have defined:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'platform' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/platform[/:controller/:region/:id[/:action]]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'region' => '[0-9a-z]{2,4}',
                    'id' => '[0-9a-z-]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'platform',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

And here is my navigation:

```
'navigation' => array(
    'default' => array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Home',
            'route' => 'home',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Account',
            'route' => 'zfcuser',
            'pages' => array(
                array(
                    'label' => 'Dashboard',
                    'route' => 'zfcuser',
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => 'Sign In',
                    'route' => 'zfcuser/login',
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => 'Sign Out',
                    'route' => 'zfcuser/logout',
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => 'Register',
                    'route' => 'zfcuser/register',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Platform v2 BETA',
            'route' => 'platform',
        ),
    ),
),
```

I display a top-level menu on every page in my layout like so:

```
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <?php echo $this->navigation('navigation')
                                    ->menu()
                                    ->setMinDepth(0)
                                    ->setMaxDepth(0)
                                    ->setUlClass('nav')
                                    ->render(); ?>
                </div>
```

My navigation appears correctly and has the right section activated for home and the zfcuser routes. It is the platform route which I am having problems with. If I go to `/platform` the menu will be activated. However, when I browse to any other page in the module (eg. `/platform/pendulum/na/af455e`) there is no active menu and no breadcrumbs. The problem seems to be that the controller/action on these other pages are not the same as the default specified by the route.

How can I get any successful route match to cause the menu to activate?

Comment: I had a similar problem,
this solution helped me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18878776/5932318

Answer (score -3):

Put something like this in

```
  'invokables' => array(
        'Application\Controller\Platform'       => 'Application\Controller\PlatformController')
```

**and replace default from your above like this**

```
 'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Platform',
                'action' => 'index',
            ),
```

**Application** is Module Name In My Case

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question.